# Add results columns to existing BigQuery table using Apache Beam

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I would like to add columns which is a result of two existing columns in BigQuery. I am using Apache Beam to read from BigQuery and then process it and update the results to the same BigQuery table as a new column.

Comment: Can you share the code of what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Beam BigQuery connector does not *explicitly* support [BigQuery DML](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language), however you can write a pipeline to insert the result of your processing into a separate table, and after the pipeline runs, run a DML statement to update the column in the original table using that auxiliary table.

Alternatively, if your processing logic can be expressed in SQL, you're probably better off just implementing it as an SQL DML statement without using a pipeline.